# archive created by PHP ZipArchive class opened with WinRar but not with WinZip

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using ZipArchive class to zip my files residing over server. I am able to extract the downloaded ZIP with WinRar but not with WinZip. And if i download the created ZIP directly from server via FileZilla then i am able to extract it with Winzip.

Please have a look at the following script that I am using:-

```
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }

    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)  {

        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);    
    }

    $zip->close();

    //get the size of the archive
    $zipped_size = filesize($archive_file_name);

    //set the required headers
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    //header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Cache-Control: public", false);
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    //header("Content-type: application/x-zip-compressed");
    //header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CV-archive.zip");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: utf-8");
    header('Pragma: public');
    //header("Content-Length:". "$zipped_size");

    ob_clean(); //ob_clean and flush are required to make sure no extra line space is generated before output as it will corrupt the zip archive
    flush();
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    unlink("$archive_file_name"); // Now delete the temp file (some servers need this option)
    foreach($file_names as $files)  {
        unlink($file_path.$files);  
}
    exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your download script is adding additional output, possibly a white space before the `<?php` tag or maybe after the `?>` tag in some included file. Or maybe `unlink($file_path.$files);` is displaying a warning.

Comment: Hi Alvaro thanks for your reply...but i have checked there are no white spaces before <?php and i have used ob_clean() and flush() to make sure no line spaces or white spaces come before actual output.

Comment: I suppose you've only checked that and you haven't inspected the ZIP file itself. Please do. You can also use a file comparison tool.

Comment: Hi Alvaro..i have resolved this issue..actually force download was creating the issue so i just gave the link to download directly from browser and it worked. Anyways thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: How can an HTTP header change the file contents?

Comment: I never said that it was changing file content..issue was when i tried to force download (using HTTP headers) the archive it was not opening with WinZip but WinRar so i tried to download the archive by giving the download link directly to browser and it worked.

Comment: Once a file lands on the hard disk it's no longer an HTTP download. If WinZip cannot open it it's because of the file contents (HTTP headers are gone). I know you're reluctant to compare both files (FTP and HTTP) but that would offer invaluable diagnose information. Whatever, you should post your findings as a proper answer (Stack Overflow encourages answering your own questions) but trying to give details so it's useful for whoever finds this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is two years old, I found the same behaviour due to a different issue. Files in my archives were of the format "\1-SOMFILENAME" .. and it happens that win rar has been able to extract the files, but Windows Archiver do not.

It turned out the first \ escapes next character and windows archiver is not able to deal with that.